# npx create-react-app my-app stuck at done in xx.xs through yarn manager

Tags: html, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

[This is command i have used to install react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgkmp.jpg)

> I want to learn react but when I tried to installed it through command **npx create-react-app my-app**  ,which installs some file then stops by displaying message done in 98.66s

After it the cursor is blinking so i thought command is still working but it was'nt i waited for about half an hour the screen was'nt changed so i tried go to the directory of my-app and typed the command yarn start.

It was showing an Error:

yarn run v1.22.4
error Command "start" not found.
info visit......

This is because of the **npx create-react-app** has not installed the src directory in my my-app folder i don't know why.

Comment: if you check your package.json then you will find that there is no "start" command inside the scripts of the package.json file.

Comment: Why I have to add start script , in the official sites they haven't changed anything in the json file rather it works fine with commands yarn start or npm start.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are a few ways to solve this problem. Check Below let me know if they worked for you. If not, we will figure it out.

**Method 1**

Simply run this command `yarn add react-scripts` and then try your installation again.

**Method 2**

include the start command inside of the package.json file.
eg:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "some command to be run", // you need to add this line
  "test": "(eslint lib || true) && jest"
}
```

**Method 3**

run `npm install` first. Then `npm run` or `yarn`  then `yarn start`

**Bonus Method**

RUN!!! The world is about to end! There is no solution! We are all going to die... eventually! :D